# jQuery Waypoints Fire Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am using http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints and
I need to do some action when the user scrolls down to the area with the class `div1`. However, I need it only fire once and not every time the user scrolls to that location. — **only once**

```
$('.div1').waypoint(function(direction) 
{
    alert(CARRY OUT MY ACTION);
});
```

This needs to only happen on the first scroll to that section — up or down.

Answer (score 33):

`triggerOnce()` is replaced with `destroy()`.
Just add `this.destroy()`.

```
$('.div1').waypoint(function(direction){
    alert('CARRY OUT MY ACTION')
    this.destroy()
});
```

For more options check the [API of Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/).

Answer (score 14):

If you pass a second parameter to the `waypoint()` function, you can include an object of configuration options. Setting the `triggerOnce` option to true will make the plugin behave the way you'd like.

```
$('.div1').waypoint(function(direction) 
{
    alert('CARRY OUT MY ACTION');
},  
{ 
    triggerOnce: true 
});
```

Comment: Please note the waypoints API has changed in version 3.0. http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/destroy/

Comment: Is there a way to destroy all the waypoints in a particular element within the handler?

Answer (score 1):

In the new API, it seems that there is no triggerOnce option anymore, but still can be used the `waypoint.disable()` method after the first call

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `this.destroy()` at the end of your handler function. Here is an example that will work:

```
$('.div1').waypoint(function(direction){

    handler: function(direction) {

        alert('CARRY OUT MY ACTION');

        this.destroy();

    }

});
```

Also see the [waypoint.destroy()](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/destroy/) documentation.